# LispCabinet read-line freezing

Tags: windows-7, lisp, freeze

I've been playing with LispCabinet off and on for a bit, learning in my spare time. What works on my PC at home, and my work PC at my old job, seems to freeze Emacs or SLIME at my new job.

I'm going through Practical Common Lisp for a refresher, and this function:

```
(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))
```

works perfectly at home. Running it at work, however, freezes after entering a few characters until I kill the interpreter. I've narrowed it down to

```
(read-line *query-io*)
```

as running that by itself will cause a freeze. The following also fail:

```
(read *query-io*)
(read-line *standard-input*)
(read *standard-input*)
```

I'm completely stumped as to what could be causing this. Any ideas?

I'm running LispCabinet 0.3.3 on Windows 7 Pro SP1.

LispBox works fine, but even reverting to earlier versions of LispCabinet, I still encounter the same failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files are intended only for execution from the Emacs command shell or external cmd shell launched form the '((' menu (all environment variables are set up during the Emacs initialization).
I just tried to execute the code you posted on the stackoverflow in
the SBCL SLIME REPL (it also could be launched from the '((' menu), and it works fine on my installation.
The issue is still present in the shell and I suppose that this is an SBCL unicode I/O issue (LispCabinet uses unofficial version of SBCL).
You may try to install the official version into the '/bin/sbcl/' or use ClozureCL instead, if you want to use the command shell instead of SLIME REPL (but SLIME is much more convenient).

Comment: I think I figured it out. I tried the official SBCL, and it worked on the command line version, but still not in Emacs. I'm pretty sure it was either Anything mode or the auto-complete. When it froze, the status bar showed "pipelined request swank:fuzzy-completions <what_i_typed_so_far>". Reinstalling without auto-complete-mode and anything-mode has it working again. I'll try and figure out which of the two it was.

Comment: Turned out to be auto-complete-mode that broke it.

Comment: Nope. Just verified it's still broken on a fresh install of Windows 8. Have to run M-x auto-complete-mode to turn it off before I run any code that reads input.

Comment: It's very hard to figure out what actually happens with the AC mode. It's possible to add the following line into the .emacs file to disable it in the REPL buffer: `(setq ac-modes (delq 'slime-repl-mode ac-modes))`